# Запретить scroll основного содержимого страницы при вызове модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть фиксированное модальное окно, и основное содержимое. Хочу добиться того, чтобы при вызове модального окна содержимое боди оставалось в фиксированном состоянии.

Перерыв много тем на форумах, однозначно правильного решения я не нашел. Дабы напрасно вам не пришлось проявлять свои экстрасенсорные способности прикрепляю сниппет того что описал выше.

```js
var buttonOpen = document.querySelector(".button-open")
var buttonClose = document.querySelector(".button-close")
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal-feedback");

buttonOpen.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  modal.classList.add("modal-feedback-show");
});

buttonClose.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  modal.classList.remove("modal-feedback-show");
});
```

```css
.modal-feedback {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #f74b4b;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal-feedback-show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-open">Открыть окно</button>

<div class="modal-feedback">
  <p>Текст</p>
  <button class="button-close">Закрыть</button>
</div>

<p>Практический опыт показывает, что рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнить важнейшие задания по разработке системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров.</p>

<p>Повседневная практика показывает, что консультация с профессионалами из IT требует от нас анализа направлений прогрессивного развития!</p>

<p>Дорогие друзья, реализация намеченного плана развития требует определения и уточнения всесторонне сбалансированных нововведений.</p>

<p>Практический опыт показывает, что рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнить важнейшие задания по разработке системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров.</p>
```

Comment: http://bortvlad.ru/css-verstka/zapretit-scroll-css-jquery/

Comment: [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Comment: @VerNick Спасибо. Очень удачное решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант навесить на `body` `overflow: hidden`:

```js
var buttonOpen = document.querySelector(".button-open")
var buttonClose = document.querySelector(".button-close")
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal-feedback");
var body = document.querySelector("body");

buttonOpen.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  modal.classList.add("modal-feedback-show");
  body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
});

buttonClose.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  modal.classList.remove("modal-feedback-show");
  body.style.overflow = '';
});
```

```css
.modal-feedback {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #f74b4b;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal-feedback-show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-open">Открыть окно</button>

<div class="modal-feedback">
  <p>Текст</p>
  <button class="button-close">Закрыть</button>
</div>

<p>Практический опыт показывает, что рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнить важнейшие задания по разработке системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров.</p>

<p>Повседневная практика показывает, что консультация с профессионалами из IT требует от нас анализа направлений прогрессивного развития!</p>

<p>Дорогие друзья, реализация намеченного плана развития требует определения и уточнения всесторонне сбалансированных нововведений.</p>

<p>Практический опыт показывает, что рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнить важнейшие задания по разработке системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров.</p>

<p>Практический опыт показывает, что рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнить важнейшие задания по разработке системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров.</p>

<p>Практический опыт показывает, что рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнить важнейшие задания по разработке системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров.</p>

<p>Практический опыт показывает, что рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнить важнейшие задания по разработке системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров.</p>

<p>Практический опыт показывает, что рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнить важнейшие задания по разработке системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров.</p>
```

Comment: Да, но я заметил у этого способа один минус. При закрытии окна, содержимое боди открывается сначала. Т.е если пользователь открыл окно где то в середине страницы, то после закрытия окна, его отбросит в самое начало страницы.

Comment: Если честно не сталкивался с такой проблемой, возможно это происходит не из-за `overflow: hidden`, а каких-то сайт эффектов в вашем коде. Только что еще раз проверил на собственном проекте где используется данная методика - скролл остается на том же месте))